# Reverse NSInteger in a Loop For

Tags: objective-c, for-loop

I'm working on this for loop and it works perfectly .. I regularly returns the list of found numbers, but I need that for loop give me back the numbers in descending order ... from 30 to 18 and not by the 18-30 as now ... Someone can 'give me a help in this?

I post the code in question

```
  for (NSInteger i = 18; i <= 30; i += 2) {


    self.axisY_Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, paddingValue, 35, 20)];
    self.axisY_Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)i];
    self.axisY_Label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.axisY_Label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:13];


    UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_axisY_Label.frame.size.width, _axisY_Label.center.y, self.frame.size.width, 0.3)];
    line.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    line.alpha = .2;
    [self addSubview:line];

    paddingValue += _axisY_Label.frame.size.width;
    [self addSubview:_axisY_Label];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange `from` and `to` parameters and count backwards

```
for (NSInteger i = 30; i >= 18; i -= 2) { ...
```